# PHP http_response_code always gets activated

Tags: php, http, jwt

I'm trying to set a 403 error when there is no JWT present with HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE. But I get this status even if the token is stored.

```
if(!$jwt){
            http_response_code(403);
            //print_r(json_encode($jwt));
            exit();
        }
```

I tried to remove HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS but then everything works fine and I don't get the $jwt printed.

Comment: Are you sure? What does `$jwt` contain? When did the print_r show when you uncommented it?

Comment: @aynber for example when I try this code ``` if(!$jwt){
            //http_response_code(403);
            print_r(json_encode("no jwt"));
            exit();
        } else{
            print_r(json_encode("there is a jwt"));
        }``` I get "there is a jwt" but when I uncomment the http_response_code I still get the 403 status :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.